# getting image from firebase storage not working

Tags: flutter, dart

i am new to flutter and i am trying to make an app which take data from user and make a widget out of it (Classified ads), so far everything is working. but the images from firebase storage is not loading, i have the image url in database ,

for the name its working

```
Text(snapshot.data.documents[index]['item Name'],),
```

but for images it gives error

```
index == null
  ? Image.asset('assets/afghan.png')
: Image.network(snapshot.data.documents[index]['image 1 Url'],),
```

the ERROR

Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///data/user/0/com.example.thisOne/cache/image_picker1382407617041908118.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
Image.network(snapshot.data.documents[index]['image 1 Url'],)
```

into this:

```
Image.file(snapshot.data.documents[index]['image 1 Url'],)
```

---

The image url is not valid, this is how you have to save the image in the database:

```
          StorageTaskSnapshot snapshot = await storage
              .ref()
              .child("images/$imageName")
              .putFile(file)
              .onComplete;
          if (snapshot.error == null) {
            final String downloadUrl =
                await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
            await Firestore.instance
                .collection("images")
                .add({"url": downloadUrl, "name": imageName});
            setState(() {
              isLoading = false;
            });
```

You are not saving it correctly to the database, you need to get the `downloadUrl` from firebase storage which will contain a valid url (https://...) and add it to Firestore. Then you can use `Image.network`

Comment: thanks , but i didnt figure it out can you write me a function to upload the image and get the URL

Comment: `putFile` uploads the file to storage and `getDownlosdUrl` gets the url